# Flutter load list with id

Tags: flutter

Hey how can i load one of several lists with one id?

my lists look like this

```
List one = [
    {'name': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Germany'},
  ];

List two = [
    {'name': 'BMW'},
    {'name': 'Audi'},
  ];
```

i need load one of this list like this

```
 body: Column(
          children: one.map((info) {
            return Container(
              child: SizedBox(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      info['name'],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
```

all i want is to load one of the two lists depending on the id of my previous page

for example id 1 was passed then two.map should be loaded

I have created a variable on this page that is also passed, I tried to use variable.map but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many lists, put your Lists into a List. With your variable from the previous page you can call the right List out of your data.

```
data[variable].map(info) { ....... }
```

**Edit:**

1. Step

create **List<List>** data ; their you can save all your list; when you want your List "one".

```
const List<List<dynamic>> data = [[{'name': 'USA'},{'name': 'Germany'},],[ {'name': 'BMW'},{'name': 'Audi'},]];
```

2. Step

put it into your widget tree and call the right data with your variable(x)(INTEGER) to get the right list and map it as before:

```
body: Column(
          children: data[x].map((info) {
            return Container(
              child: SizedBox(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      info['name'],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
```

If that isn't working you may have another problem in another topic.

Tom

Comment: how i put my lists i one list?

Comment: and if i make this [variable].map i have error on info['name'] (the operator isnt defined)

Comment: Hmm the lists not in the main its a screen with only a StatelessWidget and if i make a void main after this have a error on data[1].map((info) say undefined name data

Comment: Okay I understand, that's only a example above, of course you can't put a method into a stateless widget. Can you share the whole code?

Comment: is it possible to translate this list? I've seen the translation runs through json would that work?

Comment: If you are right with the solution, just mark it as solution. Easier for people who have the same problem. Thanks

Comment: What do you understand about translating a list? You cannot translate a whole list with json, just the objects/String which are in the list.

Comment: Hey my list is so long and now its laggy, i need to use ListViewBuilder how i can use .map in ListViewBuilder?

Comment: Do you know how to use a ListViewBuilder? If not look at that should be self explaining. https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb ;Or look at the documentation at flutter docs.

Comment: Yes i know but i dont know how i can use the data[x].map((info) { in the builder

Answer (score 0):

ternary operator helps you

```
body: Column(
          children:Your variable == 1
             ? one.map((info) {
                 return Container(
                   child: SizedBox(
                   child: Text(
                   info['name'],
                 ),
                ),
               );
              }).toList()
              : one.map((info) {
                return Container(
                 child: SizedBox(
                    child: Text(
                       info['name'],
                     ),
                    ),
                  );
                 }).toList()),
      );
```